# How to design below form using Bootstrap 4.4.1

Tags: bootstrap-4

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class='row'>
        <div class="col">
          <p>
            <b>Date:</b><span>April, 30th 2020</span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <b>Truck No</b>: <span>KA 33 5707</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <b>Commodity:</b><span>RICE</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class="col">
          <p>
            <b>Wagon No:</b><span>183340</span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <b>Bags Loaded:</b><span>425</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <b> Truck Chit No:</b>
          <a href="url">1982</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <p>Truck Chit</p>
          <img width="64" height="100" title="core" style="cursor: pointer;"
            src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/jwwhitt"/>
          <p>Scanned at  Goods shed</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <p>Driver Photo & Name</p>
          <img width="64" height="100" title="core" style="cursor: pointer;"
            src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/jwwhitt" />
          <p>Ramesh</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I am facing some alignment issues: how to set different height and width to the row and columns. I want to design same as image:

[image: I want to design same as image]

How to match image column height and text column height to look form good?

I want to design form using Bootstrap 4.4.1.

Comment: Vinod Alampally - we need a lot more information to be able to help you. Images alone are no substitute for code samples. We'll have a better chance of helping you if you give us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Maybe go have a read here as well - [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Added code snippet  please help out

Answer (score 1):

It's not perfectly clear what you want. I've done a bit for you anyway. I believe this looks like the image you provided.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 d-flex flex-column align-items-left justify-content-around">
   <p class="mt-1"><b>Date:</b><span>April, 30th 2020</span></p>
   <p class=""><b>Commodity:</b><span>RICE</span></p>
   <p class="mb-3"><b>Wagon No:</b><span>183340</span></p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-4 d-flex flex-column align-items-left justify-content-around">
   <p class="mt-1"><b>Truck No</b>: <span>KA 33 5707</span></p>
   <p class=""><b> Truck Chit No:</b> <a href="url">1982</a></p>
   <p class="mb-3"><b>Bags Loaded:</b><span>425</span></p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-4">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
     <p>Truck Chit</p>
     <img width="64" height="100" title="core" style="cursor: pointer;"
        src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/jwwhitt" />
     <p>Scanned at  Goods shed</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
     <p>Driver Photo & Name</p>
     <img width="64" height="100" title="core" style="cursor: pointer;"
        src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/jwwhitt" />
     <p>Ramesh</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```